# Assembly Programming beginner

Tags: assembly, x86, asmx, masm

I am new to Assembly programming and I could not find a place to start. I am running windows8 32bit on Intel i5 processor. Please guide me and help me with some good books sources that can take me from bottom up. Also I am trying to compile the following hello world program under Masm32 and it gives an error which says "Cannot open file win32.inc"

```
         .486p
         .model  flat,STDCALL
include  win32.inc

extrn            MessageBoxA:PROC
extrn            ExitProcess:PROC

.data

HelloWorld db "Hello, world!",0
msgTitle db "Hello world program",0

.code
Start:
         push    MB_ICONQUESTION + MB_APPLMODAL + MB_OK
         push    offset msgTitle
         push    offset HelloWorld
         push    0
         call    MessageBoxA

         push 0
         call ExitProcess
ends
end Start
```

Please let me know what's wrong and how I can get it to work.

Also the following code when built gives the error "Cannot open input file Test.exe"

```
.586p
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL
_DATA SEGMENT
_DATA ENDS
_TEXT SEGMENT
START:
RET
_TEXT ENDS
END START
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: MASM32 includes a lot of sample programs. Why don't you start with those?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to specify the full path to where win32.inc lives.  I'm guessing that you're developing your code in a different directory from where masm32 lives, so it can't find the bundled include files.